# Calling React Hook inside React Function Component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-functional-component

```
import { useOptInOut } from "../../hooks/useOptInOut/useOptInOut";
import withTranslation, { WithTranslationComponentProps } from '../../hoc/WithTranslation';

const DataConsent = (props: WithTranslationComponentProps) => {
    const optStatusResponse = useOptInOutStatus();
    const enable = optStatusResponse.value?.enabled;

  const selectOptType = () => {
       if (enable) {
            setOptInOut(false);
        } else if (!enable) {
            setOptInOut(true);
        }
  }

   const onSubmit = () => {
      const response = useOptInOut(optType);
     }

return (


               <section className="app-section-container">
                <div className="radio">
                        {!enable && <label>
                            <input type="radio" value="optIn" onChange={selectOptType} />
                            <b>Opt-in: </b>
                        </label>}

                          {enable && <label>
                            <input type="radio" value="optOut" onChange={selectOptType} />
                            <b>Opt-out:  </b> 
                        </label>}

             <div className="cta-buttons">
                    <button className={`ui primary button`} onClick={onSubmit}>
                        SUBMIT
                    </button>
                </div>

                <section>
)

export default withScrollTop(withTranslation(DataConsent as any));
```

Hello,

I am trying to make a call on clicking on the submit button, and this call will use a hook to make a POST API call.

My question is, I am not able to make a call to the hook from my function component. Please have a look at my code and let me know if you can help me out here.

Here is the error message I am facing.

"React Hook "useOptInOut" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks."

Comment: the error message is correct - call your hook at the root level of your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is expected when you try to use a `React hook` inside of a function or anywhere else other than the top-level of the component.

The problem is:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  const response = useOptInOut(optType);
}
```

If your hook relies on `optType` then executes right away to give you a response, then you need to lightly refactor the hook so that it returns a callback function instead.

Update your hook to look more like this:

`useOptInOut.ts`

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const useOptInOut = () => {
  const getOptInOut = useCallback((optTypes) => {
    // your normal call logic moved to here...
    const response = await ...;
    return response;
  }, [optTypes]);
  
  return getOptInOut;
};
```

Now inside your component you can properly bring the `useOptInOut` hook to the top-level where it needs to be:

```
const DataConsent = (props: WithTranslationComponentProps) => {
    const optStatusResponse = useOptInOutStatus();
    const getOptInOut = useOptInOut(); // <--- get the callback, but don't execute yet
    // ...
};
```

Now update your `onSubmit`:

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
  const response = await getOptInOut(optType);
}
```